# How to test if there is an _NSCFConstantString in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, uipopovercontroller

Alright, so I have a Popover, containing a tableView, that is populated by an `NSMutableArray` filled with strings. But there is always one `blank/empty` string in my `NSMutableArray` and in turn always an empty cell in my popover table. I've single stepped my project and found that the empty string is a string constant(_NSCFConstantString).

I've tried to get rid of the empty string occurrence by doing a simple empty string test:

```
[str isEqualToString:@""]
```

But this doesn't work, I'm assuming because the empty string in my array is of type _NSCFConstantString...?

So what I'm wondering is if there is a way to test if an object is of type `_NSCFConstantString`, or if you guys have a better way to test if a string is empty...

Here is my full code that pertains to my issue:

```
    NSString *str;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.flattenedDocList count]; i++) {
        str = [self.flattenedDocList objectAtIndex:i];
        if(![str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            [self.flattenedDocList removeObject: str];
            NSLog(@"Just Deleted:%@",str);
        }else if([str isEqualToString:@""]){
            [self.flattenedDocList removeObject: str];
            NSLog(@"Just Deleted:%@",str);
        }
    }
```

The first if-statement is a check to get rid of any `NSNull` objects in my array. Unfortunately this doesn't get rid of the string constants :/

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I made the rookie mistake of modifying an NSMutableArray while enumerating. Also, `H2CO3` was right, `_NSCFConstantString` IS a concrete subclass of NSString, so we can use all NSString methods on them.

Here is a good way to modify an NSMutableArray while enumerating it.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.docList];
self.listForThePopover = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *str;
for (int i = 0; i < [tempArray count]; i++) {

    str = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    //NSLog(@"~str:%@~",str);

    //check if the str is of the NSString class AND if it's NOT empty
    if(([str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) && (![str isEqualToString:@""])){

        //add the string to the list that we want to actually use.
        [self.listForThePopover addObject:str];
        //NSLog(@"Just Added:%@",str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this does not work, I'm assuming because the empty string in my array is of type `_NSCFConstantString`...?

Not quite. `_NSCFConstantString` is a concrete subclass of `NSString`, so it should work.

Maybe the string is not **really** and empty string, or it isn't in the array. Check if it's a space (or more of them), by accident. Examine its `length` property, etc.

By the way, **it's a very bad idea to modify a mutable collection while enumerating it,** it can lead to logic errors. Maybe that's also part of your current problem in this case.

Comment: You're right it's not really an empty string, and it's not really in the array. It doesn't get looped over, hence why it doesn't pass any of the tests or print out. So I don't understand why I see it in the array when i print the entire array out and why it appears in my tableView. I read that NSCFConstantString is used for string optimization in the compiler, so maybe it's the white space in my strings? But I don't know...

Comment: @Jim-Dingo `__NSCFConstantString` is a class used for string literals. When you write a constant string in the code like this: `@"foo"`, then the compiler emits an instance of this class. If it's not in the array, then you have a logic error somewhere in your code. Perhaps show the output of your log too?

Comment: @H2CO3You were right about the logic errors that can occur if you try to modify an array while enumerating it. The empty string never passed the tests because it was never enumerated! I had originally set up the enumeration process to carefully take into account the logic errors, BUT made the stupid move of changing it around (it was late and I had been coding all day so I wasn't thinking clearly xD )